# kubernetes use nfs persistent volumes with a root user in a pod

Tags: kubernetes, root, nfs, persistent-volumes

ok I am banging my head now agaainst he wall for serveral days...

my usecase:
I am on my own bare metal cloud, I am running ubuntu machines and setup kubernetes on 4 machines one master 3 workers. I created a private registry and cert-manager etc etc.

also nfs shares are on the worker nodes

i have a piece of software that **has to run as root inside a pod** now i want this root user to store data on a presistent volume on a nfs share.

root_squash is biting me in the but...

I have created volumes and claims and all works ok if i am not root inside the pod. when root the files on the nfs shares are squashed to nobody:nogroup and the root user inside the pod can no longer use them...

what to do?

1) export nfs share with the no_root_squash option but this seems like a very bad idea given security issues, not sure if this can be mitigated by firewall rules alone?

2) i trid all kinds of securityContext options for fsGroup and uid en gid mount options, all work ok as long as you are not root in de pod... but i am not sure if i understand this in full so

My pc yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: s03-pv0004
  annotations:
    pv.beta.kubernetes.io/gid: "1023"
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: slow
  mountOptions:
    - hard
    - nfsvers=4.1
  nfs:
    path: /data/k8s/pv0004
    server: 212.114.120.61
```

As you van see i created a dedicated  nfsuser with uid 1023 and use this to make the pods store data as this user... works fine as long as i am not rooot inside the pods...

The pods i am running are MarkLogic pods in a stateful set like so:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: marklogic
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: marklogic
  serviceName: "ml-service"
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: marklogic
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1023
... more
```

runAsUser: 1023 works but again not if i want to be root inside the pod...

My question: Can it be done, run a pod as root and still use nfs as persistent volume with a secure nfs share(that is not using no_root_squash) ???

or do i need to drop the idea of nfs and move to an alternative like glusterfs?

Comment: I have a similar setup, and personally use no_root_squash, but maybe give a try to the dynamic NFS client provisioner: https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nfs-client-provisioner

It seems it creates the files with 0777 permissions - not sure on how it would reflect on your NFS drive though: https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/blob/master/nfs-client/cmd/nfs-client-provisioner/provisioner.go#L69

Additionally, you can specify the client IPs for the NFS drive in /etc/exports file, so imo no_root_squash shouldn't be a big security issue.

Answer (score 1):

**I will try to answer in very simple steps:**

**1. You can even make root_squash to work for k8s :**

```
- run your containers as non root user: 1023 in your case

- chown -R 1023:1023 <nfs dir>
```

**2. You can make no_root_squash to work for k8s:**

```
- run your containers as root user: 0 

- chown -R root:root <nfs dir>
```

Comment: Greats! It's works.

Answer (score 0):

I have moved from nfs storage to a local storage claim option in kubernetes. This can be annotated so a pod that needs a PV lands on the same node each time it is recreated ...